# Seeking population data for Detroit?

Tags: data, united-states, census, population

I need population and age breakdown data for Detroit. I have found census tract shapefiles but none with the attribute data that I need.

Any idea where I might find such data?

Comment: If it is open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: try https://data.detroitmi.gov/

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question in general, Shapefiles from the US Census Bureau do not come prepopulated with any of the Census Tables. See https://www.census.gov/geo/education/howtos.html for guides on how to link the tract shapefiles (geography) with Census tables. In particular, [Downloading Data from American FactFinder to use with TIGER/Line Shapefiles [PDF]](http://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/education/tiger/Downloading_AFFData.pdf) or [Joining Census Data to TIGER/Line Shapefiles [PDF]](http://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/education/tiger/JoiningTIGERshp_with_AFFdata.pdf)

However as others have pointed out, this data may also be found in ready to use format from a city GIS website. Check out Data Driven Detroit:  https://datadrivendetroit.org. They have several sets of Demographic Data, such as listed on this page: 
http://portal.datadrivendetroit.org/datasets/?group_id=25cbacb151854daba75685f6f1a4a7f2&q=demographic&sort_by=relevance